# What is the probability of guessing a Hamiltonian cycle in the following graph

Tags: probability, hamiltonian-path

Would you give any hint to solve task?
"What is the probability of guessing a Hamiltonian cycle in the following graph?"

Pic:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Z3Qu.png

Comment: What are the rules of guessing?

Comment: There are no rules given

Comment: Then I guess the unique Hamiltonian cycle obtained by omitting the middle vertical edge. Probability 1.

Comment: But how does this change with a vertical edge? Two paths can be selected from each node of a vertical edge. So, I need to decrease the probability, by something like (2*1/9)/2. And i'm stuck on this moment.

Comment: I would like to help, but you have not given a clear description of the problem. A worked example on a smaller graph would help.

Comment: This is all the definition that was in task. Thanks for the idea and your time.